# NumPy sort function returns None

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have one simple program below:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(8)
new = arr.sort()
new1 = np.sort(arr)
print new
print new1
```

I expected the two new arrays to be the same a sorted array, but instead, `new` is `None`, `new1` is what I expected, what is the difference between two methods to sort?

Comment: The [`sort()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) acts *in-place*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) for `numpy.ndarray.sort`:

> Sort an array, in-place.

If you want a sorted copy of the original array, rather than sorting in place, you should use `numpy.sort`, which returns a copy, as you saw.