# sorting by field numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this code:

```
def readFile(filename):
    a = open(filename,'r')
    strs = np.array(0,dtype=[('nstr','d'),('test','f')])
    for i in a.readlines():
        if i[0] != '#':
            line = i.split()
            if len(line) > 0:
                tmp_strs = np.array(1,dtype=[('nstr','d'),('test','f')])
                tmp_strs['nstr'] = int(line[0])
                tmp_strs['test'] = float(line[1])
                strs = np.append(strs,tmp_strs)
    return strs
```

Now I'd like to sort this numpy array following the nstr field. This is easy done with the sort function of the numpy array. Anyway I bumped into a strange behavior which I cannot understand.
If I do something like:

```
test = readFile(filename)
test.sort(order='nstr')
```

everything works fine. But if I change the return inside the function like

```
return strs.sort(order='nstr')
```

The return Value is None... could someone explain to me why this is happening? I do not have any explanation

Comment: Reread `sort`.  What does it return or do?

Comment: Collecting a list of tuples, and doing one array build at the of the loop is faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy sort function returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023833/numpy-sort-function-returns-none)

Answer (score 0):

The function you call is actually **numpy.ndarray.sort**, it will **change ndarray itself** but return None.
See more detail [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort).
The function you want to call should be **numpy.sort**，see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).